Anyway to mass edit and mass export public links in sitecore content hub
I have 150 assets and I want to edit all of the public links to be the file names. I then want to mass export all of these public links so I can send them to someone.

In order to export as well as edit the public links for the asset, you will need to first create the Export Profile with the following settings.
{
 "properties":{
   "Title",
   "Description",
   "FileName"
 },
 "relations": {
   "AssetToPublicLink": {
      "exportRelatedEntities": true
    }
  }
}

Note: Inside the relation AssetToPublicLink,exportRelatedEntities is set as true in order to export public links along with the asset.
You will need to thereafter attach the Export Profile created above in the Selection component of the Assets page as below, under the Export Excel Settings.

This will export the Assets along with the PublicLinks in the separate tab. There in you can modify the public links and import the modified sheet back to Content Hub again.
More details on the export profiles can be found here.
https://doc.sitecore.com/ch/en/users/41/content-hub/manage--export-profiles.html
Hope this helps!!! Let me know in case you face any issues.
